# Spark table and Ranger Row filtering

Tags: apache-spark, apache-ranger

Reading the docs we have the following doubt:

- For a Spark table created by saveAsTable(...) and using the Hive metastore

  - can one use Apache Ranger to enforce row level filters on such a table?

It is not clear from the docs. For a 'native' Hive table it is clear that this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spark-only tables this is not possible. Confirmed with Ranger test.

Answer (score 1):

For Spark-only tables, this requires a Ranger-based tool like Privacera.

Comment: Need to be more specific.

Comment: @thebluephantom check this https://privacera.com